# Validate against DocBook schema in OS X on the command-line

Tags: macos, xsd, docbook

What's the simplest way to validate XML files against the DocBook 5 schema from the command-line?

In particular, I'm talking about DocBook documents that are split up across several files and included with the `<xi:include href="..."/>`.

The specific use case here is finding schema violations in proposed changes in the [OpenStack documentation](http://github.com/openstack/openstack-manuals).

If I open up files in the [oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/) GUI editor, it will identify schema violations, but I'd like to be able to run these checks from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xmllint` does what I need, for example:

```
xmllint --relaxng http://www.docbook.org/xml/5.0/rng/docbookxi.rng --noout ~/openstack-manuals/doc/src/docbkx/openstack-compute-admin/bk-compute-adminguide.xml
```

This outputs a string that indicates whether validation was successful:

```
/Users/lorin/openstack-manuals/doc/src/docbkx/openstack-compute-admin/bk-compute-adminguide.xml validates
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds almost like a trick question:  if you want to validate documents from the command line, you will want to acquire a schema validator for the schema language you have in mind with a command-line interface, no?  So I guess you are asking which validators have a command-line interface?

Several XSD validators have command-line interfaces; in alphabetical order, the ones that come first to my mind are:  [MSV](http://msv.java.net/) (multi-schema validator), [Saxon-EE](http://www.saxonica.com), [Xerces C](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/), and [Xerces J](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/).  There are also partial XSD implementations in [xmllint](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) (the command-line interface to libxml) and [xsv](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~ht/xsv-status.html).  I believe that it's also possible to run at least one of Microsoft's XSD implementations from the command line, but as you mention OS X in the heading I assume that's not where you want to go.

RelaxNG validators include Jing, xmllint, and msv; all have command-line interfaces.